# Altium Efficient Usage of Signal Harness

Tags: schematics, altium, cad

I have a 16-channel differential analog input which I would like to represent through a signal harness (see below). I am new to Altium, and I am curious if there is a trick to define my harness more quickly. Specifically, is there a shortcut to generate the harness entries based on the netlabels of wires attached to a blank harness connector? Similarly, after routing my harness somewhere to be used, is there a way to simultaneously generate labeled wires for all of the harness entries to get straight to connecting them?

**First image: can we quickly generate the harness entries according to these labeled wires?**

[image: Generating Harness Entries Automatically?]

**Second image: can we automatically generate all of these wires based on the harness entries?**

[image: Expanding Created Harness Automatically?]

Comment: You can copy <Ctrl+R> & paste net labels and wires coming off of pins. If you're handy, you can write a script to auto-generate numbered net names. Suggestion, for single-digit numbered net names, name them "in01", not "in1" so they sort properly against the two-digit net names (i.e., "in12").

Comment: Awesome tip, thanks for the advice!